# axios delete .catch command doesn't exist in void

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've been trying to use an axios .delete request to delete cards from a list.

The code for the delete function is as follows:

```
deleteProduct(id: any) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;

    const apiVideoUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}`;
    //const apiManualUrl = `http://localhost:3000/manuals/${id}`;

    const options = {
      method: "DELETE"
    };

    axios
      .delete(apiVideoUrl, {})

      .then((response: any) => {
        this.setState({
          adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

I am getting two different errors from .catch and from function(error).

The error from .catch is:

```
Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)
```

And the error from (error) is:

```
Parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
```

Is there something I'm obviously missing out on?

Thank you in advance for the time and help.

Comment: You're calling `.catch` from `setState`. Please take a look at your code before posting an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are attaching the .catch() to the setState() not the .then()

change:

```
axios
      .delete(apiVideoUrl, {})

      .then((response: any) => {
        this.setState({
          adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

to:

```
axios

   .delete(apiVideoUrl, {})
   .then((response:any) => {
        this.setState({
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
        })
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to `catch` your `setState` call, not the delete request itself:

```
axios
      .delete(apiVideoUrl, {})

      .then((response: any) => {
        this.setState({
          adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
        })
       }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```